# DIV Animation issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/9BCrs/

The idea is to click Slide Left and the DIV's slide left - that works. What doesn't work is if I click Slide Right and nothing moves.

Any help is appreciated.

```
$(function(){
    $(".link1").click(function(){
        $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({left:-400}, 200);
        $(".block2").stop(true, true).animate({left:25}, 200);
    });
});

$(function(){
    $(".link2").Click(function(){
        $(".block2").stop(true, true).animate({left:450}, 200);
        $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({left:25}, 200);
    });
});
```

and HTML

```
<div id="block_container">
    <div class="block1">
        <div class="link1">Slide Left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
        <div class="link2">Slide Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo, you have an uppercase 'C' for the `click` function on the `.link2` selector.

```
$(".link2").click(...
```

It's also worth noting that you don't need to wrap each handler in it's own document ready handler.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9BCrs/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You have spelled $(".link2").Click with uppercase C. Use "click" like this

```
$(".link2").click
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed that.